# Cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Node' to 'Node &'

Tags: c++, linked-list

I really can't figure out why I'm getting these errors:

- Error    1   error C2662: 'void Node::setInfo(const Type &)'
  : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Node' to
  'Node &'
- Error    2   error C2662: 'void Node::setLink(Node *)' : cannot convert
  'this' pointer from 'const Node' to 'Node &'

Here's the program I'm doing.

Header File:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class Type>
class Node
{
private:
    Type info;
    Node<Type> *link;
public:
    // Constructors
    Node();
    Node(const Type& elem, Node<Type> *ptr);
    Node(const Node<Type> &otherNode);

    // Destructor
    ~Node();

    // Mutators and Accessors (getters and setters)
    void setInfo(const Type& elem);
    Type getInfo() const;

    void setLink(Node<Type> *ptr);
    Node<Type> * getLink() const;

    // Overload the assignment operator
    const Node<Type> & operator=(const Node<Type>&);
};

template <class Type> Node<Type>::Node()
{
    link = NULL;
}

template <class Type> Node<Type>::Node(const Type& elem, Node<Type> *ptr)
{
    info = elem;
    link = ptr;
}

template <class Type> Node<Type>::Node(const Node<Type> &otherNode)
{
    otherNode.setInfo(info); //ERROR 1
    otherNode.setLink(link); // ERROR 2
}

template <class Type> Node<Type>::~Node()
{
    // fill in this
}

template <class Type> void Node<Type>::setInfo(const Type& elem) 
{
    info = elem;
}

template <class Type> Type Node<Type>::getInfo() const
{
    return info;
}

template <class Type> void Node<Type>::setLink(Node<Type> *ptr) 
{
    link = ptr;
}

template <class Type> Node<Type> * Node<Type>::getLink() const
{
    return link;
}


template <class Type> const Node<Type> & Node<Type>::operator=(const Node<Type>& n)
{
    info = n.info;
    link = n.link;
}
```

Main File:

```
include "Node.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Node<string> *node1 = new Node<string>();
    node1->setInfo("Hello");
    Node<string> *node2 = new Node<string>("Hello World!", node1);
    Node<string> *node3 = new Node<string>(*node2);
    Node<string> *node4 = new Node<string>();
    node4->setInfo("Foo Bar");
    node4->setLink(node3);

    cout << node3->getLink()->getInfo() << endl;  // should return "hello world"

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scratching out my previous answer, because it was way off.
I got a compiler and I see what's happening.

In your copy constructor, you are passing in a const reference, and then attempting to modify that const reference.

Instead it should look like

```
template <class Type> Node<Type>::Node(const Node<Type> &otherNode)
{
    this->setInfo(otherNode.info); 
    this->setLink(otherNode.link);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked now. I couldn't figure out another way to write it.

Comment: @user3593832 - There was no need for you to write a copy constructor if this is all it will do.  See my answer concerning your assignment operator.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are attempting to modify a constant object.  Your constructor declaration is

```
template <class Type> Node<Type>::Node(const Node<Type> &otherNode)
```

The `const` means that you cannot modify the `otherNode` object.  You can only call methods on `otherNode` that are marked as `const`.  In your body you attempt to modify the `otherNode` object:

```
otherNode.setInfo(info); //ERROR 1
otherNode.setLink(link); // ERROR 2
```

In this case, I believe that properly declaring `otherNode` as `const` is saving you from another issue.  It looks like your copy constructor is actually copying your 'new' node into the source node, rather than the other way around.

Comment: I realized I couldnt modify a const object and that there was something wrong the way I was passing it. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a further problem.  Your assignment operator doesn't return a Node reference.  It doesn't return anything.  Therefore your program invokes undefined behavior if a copy-assignment is invoked.

```
template <class Type> const Node<Type> & Node<Type>::operator=(const Node<Type>& n)
{
    info = n.info;
    link = n.link;
    // so what happened to the return value?
    // return *this; // You're missing this.
}
```

However, if this is your assignment operator, then why have one?  All you're doing is what the compiler generated version will do, and that is just do a shallow copy of all the members.

Comment: Sorry about that. I fixed it in my code. The author who made assignment operator isn't necessarily a coder, but I had to use this as ref because it was part of my assignment.